# Detect if current Outlook window is a Forward Email?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, vsto, add-in

I have an Outlook plugin. I have an inspector handler that calls a method when a new window is opened. I want the method to do 'something' only if the current window is a forward message window (the window that opens when you click the forward button in an email). My current code works but it works with all new windows, including Reply/ New Email etc.

Any help how I can check to see if the new window is a forward email window?

My code:

```
...
Outlook.Inspectors olInspectors;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {  ......
        olInspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        olInspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Forward_Message_Inspector);
    }

void Forward_Message_Inspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
      //how do I check here if current window is a forward message window?
          //and then do something
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check this using `Subject` of the Email.

```
void Forward_Message_Inspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
{
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
    if (mailItem != null)
    {
        if (mailItem.Subject.StartsWith("FW: "))
        {
          //do something here
        }
    }
}
```

You can also do this by analyzing `Mail Body`

Comment: That was a great suggestion! It worked! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I'd use another approach suggest by Eric. The subject can be modified by a user or programmatically. So, you can't rely on the subject line all the time.

Answer (score 4):

You can wire up your Inspector handler/wrapper to only process windows when the `MailItem.Forward` event occurs - but you'd also need a `MailItem` handler/wrapper.

Another approach is to check the values of `PR_ICON_INDEX` (will be 262 for forwards) or `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED` (104 for forwards) on the `MailItem` using the `PropertyAccessor` object.

Comment: Great! Thanks. If I used a wrapper, I would have take this route.